# Ko grid +showing column conditionally

Tags: kogrid

```
data-bind="koGrid: { data: ViewModel.statistics,
                             columnDefs: [  { displayName: 'Name', field: 'toName', sortable: true, headerTemplate: 'TmplStatsHeader', headerClass: 'left15 ' },
                                            { displayName: 'Email', field: 'email', sortable: true, headerTemplate: 'TmplStatsHeader', headerClass: 'left30 ' },
                                         ],
```

I have a ko grid my column definition is above

I have to show Email (second column) only based on some condition.

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem? Could you paste the successful code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Cell Template](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Cell-Template-Library) to change/show the cell value based on other property.

Comment: what about hiding/showing the HEADER of the column? if you use the celltemplate you will only hide the contents of the gird, not the whole column.

Comment: I mentioned Cell Template. Its applicable to [Header Cell](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/wiki/Defining-Columns) too.